# Concatenating 1D matrices of different sizes

Tags: arrays, matlab, concatenation

I perhaps am going about this wrong, but I have data{1}, data{2}...data{i}. Within each, I have .type1, .type2.... .typeN. The arrays are different lengths, so horizontal concatenation does not work.

For simplicity sake

```
>> data{1}.type1

ans =

     1
     2
     3


>> data{2}.type1

ans =

     2
     4
     5
     6
```

Results should be [1;2;3;2;4;5;6]

I've been trying to loop it but not sure how? I will have a variable number of files (a,b..). How do I go about looping and concatenating? Ultimately I need a 1xN array of all of this..

My working code, thanks..figured it out..

```
for i = 1:Types
  currentType = nTypes{i}
  allData.(currentType)=[];
  for j = 1:nData
    allData.(currentType) = [allData.(currentType); data{j}.(currentType)(:,3)]; %3rd column
  end
end
```

Comment: `[a;b]`.  Or `vertcat(a,b)`. Or `c = {a,b}; vertcat(c{:})`

Comment: It's not "digressing" to explain your input data.  Based on your comments, it appears that your sample code is too simple to explain your actual problem.  Try some sample code a little closer to what you need.

Answer (score 0):

Look at `cat`, the first argument is the dimension. In your simple example it would be:

```
result = cat(1,a,b);
```

Which is equivalent to:

```
result = [a;b];
```

Or you can concatenate them as row vectors and transpose back to a column vector:

```
result = [a',b']';
```

For the case of a structure inside a cell array I don't think there will be any way around looping. Let's say you have a cell array with `M` elements and `N` "types" as the structure fields for each element. You could do:

```
M=length(data);
newData=struct;
for i=1:M
    for j=1:N
       field=sprintf('type%d',j); % //field name
       if (M==1), newData.(field)=[]; end % //if this is a new field, create it
       newData.(field)=[newData.(field);data{i}.(field)];
    end
 end
```

Comment: yes but what if I have an N number of things to concatenate?

Comment: Assuming they are in a cell array as you suggested above, `result = vertcat(data{:})` or `result=cat(1,data{:})`

Comment: I need to concatenate data{1}.type1 and data{2}.type1 ... same for type2, type3...N

Comment: I think this is what you're looking for, is N the number of values in data or the number of "types". If it is the number of types I would highly recommend changing your format as addressing structure names dynamically is no fun.

Comment: thanks but that is what I've tried and it concatenates everything into one column. I need multiple columns or structure elements.